# Qualifying Range in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm getting the '1004 Runtime error' for not fully qualifying my code, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that's causing the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.  Here is my code:

```vb
Sub SAPMacro()
    Dim PeggedWBS as Range
    Dim CostObject As Range
    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sFindHeader As String
    Dim sNewHeader As String
    Dim rngCol As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set rngHeaders = Worksheets("Insert Zbuyr Export").Range("1:1")
    
    sFindHeader = "Pegged WBS"
    sNewHeader = "Pegged WBS Stripped"

    Set PeggedWBS = rngHeaders.Find(what:=sFindHeader)

    Set ws = Worksheets("Insert Zbuyr Export")

    With ws
        LastRow = ws.cells(.find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
     
        PeggedWBS.Offset(0,1).EntireColumn.Insert
        PeggedWBS.Offset(0,1).Value = sNewHeader
    
        Set rngNewCol = Range(PeggedWBS.Offset(1,1), ws.Cells(LastRow, PeggedWBS.Offset(1,1).Columns.Column))
        rngNewCol.Cells(1,1).Formula = "=1+1"
        rngNewCol.Filldown
        rngNewCol.Copy
        rngNewCol.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        rngNewCol.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    '#### This is where I'm having my issue.  
    'The new sheet I'm calling isn't being activated, and 
    'the object isn't being defined.

    Set rngHeaders = Worksheets("Insert Pegging Export").Range("1:1")    

    sFindHeader = "Cost Object"
    sNewHeader = "Cost Object Stripped"

    Set CostObject = rngHeaders.Find(what:=sFindHeader)

    Set ws = Worksheets("Insert Pegging Export")

    With ws
        LastRow = ws.cells(.find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
     
        CostObject.Offset(0,1).EntireColumn.Insert
        CostObject.Offset(0,1).Value = sNewHeader
    
        Set rngNewCol = Range(CostObject.Offset(1,1), ws.Cells(LastRow, CostObject.Offset(1,1).Columns.Column))
        rngNewCol.Cells(1,1).Formula = "=1+1"
        rngNewCol.Filldown
        rngNewCol.Copy
        rngNewCol.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        rngNewCol.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error message?

Comment: You should specify the `LookIn` and `LookAt` parameters for `Find` in `Set CostObject = rngHeaders.Find(what:=sFindHeader)` and then test if the `Find` succeeded using `If Not CostObject Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: Hey sorry.  Once it gets to "CostObject.Offset(0,1).EntireColumn.Insert" its telling me the object isnt defined.  I believe it's because im starting the code on the first sheet and then im trying to define an object on a different sheet without firstly activating the new sheet.  But i thought the "with" statement took care of that?

Comment: That means that `CostObject` is `Nothing` and the `Find` failed.

Comment: @BigBen see my comment above

Comment: @BigBen okay, does that mean its not finding it in the Headers in my worksheet?

Comment: Fully qualifying also includes qualifying the worksheet. Is this happening in the same workbook, and does this workbook contain the code? if so, use `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Whatever")`. Is this the complete code? `ws.cells(.find` should be `ws.cells.find`.

Comment: Yes it's not finding "Cost Object" in Row1 of "Insert Pegging Export"

Answer (score 0):

### Avoiding Repetitive Code

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SAPMacro()
    
    Const wsNamesList As String = "Insert Zbuyr Export," _
        & "Insert Pegging Export"
    Const OldHeadersList As String = "Pegged WBS,Cost Object"
    Const NewHeadersList As String = "Pegged WBS Stripped,Cost Object Stripped"
    Const FormulasList As String = "=1+1,=1+1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(wsNamesList, ",")
    Dim OldHeaders() As String: OldHeaders = Split(OldHeadersList, ",")
    Dim NewHeaders() As String: NewHeaders = Split(NewHeadersList, ",")
    Dim Formulas() As String: Formulas = Split(FormulasList, ",")
    
    Dim hCell As Range
    Dim lCell As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(wsNames)
        With wb.Worksheets(wsNames(n))
            Set hCell = .Rows(1).Find(OldHeaders(n), , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
            If Not hCell Is Nothing Then
                Set lCell = .Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, _
                    xlPrevious)
                If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
                    ' This line cannot be inside the following 'With' statement.
                    hCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
                    With hCell.Offset(0, 1)
                        .Value = NewHeaders(n)
                        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
                    End With
                    With hCell.Offset(1, 1)
                        With .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
                            .Formula = Formulas(n)
                            .Value = .Value
                        End With
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next n
    
End Sub
```